# htaccess deny from *.ru or deny from .ru

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am aware that blocking by host extension can cause unwanted server load but which is correct? For example...

deny from *.ru

or

deny from .ru

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `deny from .ru`, according to the [Apache 2.2 mod_authz documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow) which say the host syntax is identical to `Allow`. They provide an example:

```
Allow from apache.org
Allow from .net example.edu
```